# URL route blocking for HTTPS proxy

Tags: c, https, proxy, webfiltering

I had this question if I could actually block a specific route on a URL (e.g., stack overflow.com/route/) via my proxy server for HTTPS. For context, I have built a proxy server in C that blocks any of the blocked URLs that I have blacklisted. But because it uses HTTP CONNECT packet from the client to establish a secure tunnel between client and destination server, which doesn't contain a host url (along with route) in the HTTP header (it only has host:port).